# Transferring data from windows hosting disk to Ubuntu hosting disk from within Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-8.1, data-transfer

I have two disks in my pc (disk 1: a SSD hosting Ubuntu. Disk 2: a mechanical hard disk hosting Windows 8.1) I basically have no internet connection on my Ubuntu operating system due to the fact that my 3G/HSPA USB receiver does not have support for Ubuntu (Drivers nor the program itself).

In other for me to make good use of my Ubuntu operating system I need programs to run on it (Duh!!). So basically my idea was to download them in Windows and then transfer them over via USB sticks. This takes a lot of time because I have to reboot every time i want to take a program and another time to install it.

Can I  do this simpler by just directly putting the files from Disk 2 to Disk 1 (Referring to the disks above)? If so, How? I can't see disk 1 in Windows and I can't open disk 2 in Ubuntu. It gives an error if I try to open it saying that it is unsafe to open an NTSF partition that has an operating system on it!

How do I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just create a third NTFS partition for Data?

Comment: Because I dont know if that can be opend aswell an because (most of all)  I don't know how to do that!!

Comment: A NTFS partition without an operating system on it would accomplish your goal.  There are numerous tutorials on how to shrink an existing partition on a disk then create a new partition, from the unallocated space.

Comment: On creating a new partition: Grab your Ubuntu disk, boot from it, use "Try Ubuntu". From within ubuntu, open a terminal (ctrl+t) and start "gparted". You can edit your partitions. Now, as gparted will tell you: YOU CAN SERIOUSLY CAUSE DAMAGE! So ftlog, make backups. Assuming you'd rather ruin your Ubuntu than your Windows, I'd suggest working on the SSD. What you can do is resize your ubuntu partition to a smaller size, then create a new NTFS partition in the remaining (now unallocated) space. Pretty easy with nice sliders and all. Google can help you a LOT if you feel uncomfortable :)

Comment: I will look into it...

Comment: I don't want to work on muy Ubuntu disk but on my windows disk (Ubuntu disk is just 128GB rahter than 1TB for my whindows disk!!)

Comment: Yeah I meant if you're gonna do something potentially harmful, you'd better do that work to your Ubuntu disk, because if something were to go wrong, reinstalling ubuntu is a lot less work :)

Comment: And I also meant... Just for transferring a couple of files to your ubuntu disk from windows, how many space do you really need? 5 GB stores a DVD, and even on a 128GB drive that's very little. Plus, the process of resizing partitions can take some time... On the SSD you'd be done in no time. But of course, if you're comfortable taking that space off your Windows drive can be done in exactly the same way and would have the same result. The new partition should be recognized and usable from both Windows and Ubuntu, no matter what disk it is on.

Comment: you are right about my ssd probebly but I will go for my windows disk, Not only do i want to transfer programs but also music,films and I dont know if that will fit my ssd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using much of the 1TB drive in windows, it should be simple to create the NTFS partition from within windows itself.

1) From within Windows, open disk management (windows key + r, type in diskmgmt.msc, press enter)
2) Shrink 1TB Windows volume (right-click on the windows partition (probably C: in your case),  click "shrink volume". Shrink the volume by 1000 MB to give yourself about 100Gigs to play with, just don't shrink it too much so that windows doesn't have room to work. If you have a 1TB drive with only 100G used, you should be able to safely shrink it by 8000 MB, leaving windows 100G free space.
3) Create a new ntfs partition on the now "unallocated space" (the amount that you shrunk your windows volume to) by using the right-click menu.
4) You should now be able to see the new NTFS partition in both Windows and Ubuntu.

There can be trouble if the volume is fragmented and data is stored all over the disk, but Windows has gotten better at automatically defragging and fixing this for you. If any errors like that occur, just run a defragment and try again.